# Get number of packets received by ping command in python

Tags: python, ping

I need a function that can return the number of packets received or loss percentage. Before I used the code below to get true/false if I receive any of the packets. This should work in Windows, but if somebody can do it suitable for Linux too, I would be thankful.

```
def ping_ip(ip):
    current_os = platform.system().lower()
    parameter = "-c"
    if current_os == "windows":
        parameter = "-n"

    command = ['ping', parameter, '4', ip]

    res = subprocess.call(command)
    return res == 0
```

Comment: We don't write code for people from scratch. Please show your attempt to extract this information and explain what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: @ForceBru after few hours of searching function that can return this kind of value I have nothing. I believe that someone can get these values just by slightly changing this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution - just do stdout of ping command and analyze it.

```
def ping_ip(ip):
    res = 0
    current_os = platform.system().lower()
    parameter = "-c"
    if current_os == "windows":
        parameter = "-n"

    si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

    command = ['ping', parameter, '4', ip]
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, startupinfo=si, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    percentage = 0

    f = process.stdout.read().decode('ISO-8859-1').split()
    for x in f:
        if re.match(r".*%.*", x):
            strArr = []
            strArr[:0] = x
            strArr = strArr[1:-1]
            listToStr = ''.join(map(str, strArr))
            percentage = int(listToStr)
    if percentage == 0:
        res = 0  # 0% loss
    elif percentage == 100:
        res = 1  # 100% loss
    else:
        res = 2  # partial loss
    return res
```